# Csvtojson module returning unwanted keys

Tags: node.js, json, csv, csvtojson

First question here,

Im trying to get a JSON object from a csv file using csvtojson npm module.

Everything works except the JSON object that i get has object keys on it:

Expected result:

```
{
 {"key": "value",
  "other_key": "other_value"
 },
 {"key": "value",
  "other_key": "other_value"
 }
}
```

Obtained:

```
{
 1:{
   "key": "value",
   "other_key": "other_value
 },
 2:{
    "key": "value",
    "other_key": "other_value
 }
}
```

My code for creating the JSON object is as follows:

```
csv({delimiter:";" }).fromFile(csv_path+name_csv)
```

The csvfile is as follows:

```
TITLE;TITLE2;TITLE3;TITLE4;TITLE5
string;string;int;string;int
string;string;int;string;int
```

Comment: those are not line numbers, those are object keys

Comment: @GrafiCode Ok, is there any way to remove them?

Comment: it depends on your CSV file. Can you please post a snippet of it?

Comment: @GrafiCode Edited it, its a pretty simple csv file, with ';' as delimiter. Thanks

Comment: could you please try adding `noheader: true` to your `csv()` call?

Comment: @GrafiCode That removes the object keys i want to remove, but the objects are {field1 : value} instead of {TITLE1: value}

Comment: uhm, I tried to run your code, I must say I don't get those keys at all... Here is my output: `[ { TITLE: 'string',
    TITLE2: 'string',
    TITLE3: 'int',
    TITLE4: 'string',
    TITLE5: 'int' },
  { TITLE: 'string',
    TITLE2: 'string',
    TITLE3: 'int',
    TITLE4: 'string',
    TITLE5: 'int' } ]`

Comment: My output is an array of objects, I'll try and formulate an answer.

Comment: @GrafiCode Wow, i don't understand what i'm doing wrong... but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this implementation:

```
const csv = require('csvtojson')

var csvStr = `TITLE;TITLE2;TITLE3;TITLE4;TITLE5
string;string;int;string;int
string;string;int;string;int`

csv({
  delimiter:";"
})
.fromString(csvStr)
.then((csvRow)=>{
    console.log(csvRow)
})
```

It outputs an array of objects:

`[ { TITLE: 'string',
    TITLE2: 'string',
    TITLE3: 'int',
    TITLE4: 'string',
    TITLE5: 'int' },
  { TITLE: 'string',
    TITLE2: 'string',
    TITLE3: 'int',
    TITLE4: 'string',
    TITLE5: 'int' } ]`

Comment: Thanks! but i figured out what was it, and now i feel dumb for asking... The object I get is just as you said, but then I print it with console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonobj)) and is than method what puts the numbers there. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the answer!